# Regular expression for less than and more than (not the symbols!)

Tags: expression, regular-language

I have a set that equals {0,1} I want to find all strings of length 3 or less that have more 0's than 1's.

I can only find threads that are relating to the symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings are the following:

```
0
00
001
010
100
000
```

A minimal DFA for the language can be found using Myhill-Nerode. We begin considering strings and say whether each one is distinguishable from previous ones.

```
e: can be followed by L, distinguishable
0: can be followed by e,0,01,10,00,00; distinguishable
1: can only be followed by 00; distinguishable
00: can be followed by e, 0 or 1; distinguishable
01: can be followed by 0 only; distinguishable
10: can be followed by 0 only; indistinguishable from 01
11: can never lead to a string in the language; distinguishable
000: can be followed by e only; distinguishable
001: can be followed by e only; same as 000
010: can be followed by e only; same as 000, 001
100: can be followed by e only; same as 000, 001, 010
???: all other strings of length 3 never lead to a string in L, like 11
????: strings of length over 3 never lead to a string in L, like 11
```

This gives us the following minimal DFA:

```
 .
 |
 v
(e)--0-->(0)---0-->(00)
 |        |          |
 1        1         0,1
 |        |          |
 v        v          V
(1)--0-->(01)--0-->(000)
 |        |          |
 1        1         0,1
 |        |          |
 v        v          v
(11)<--\--/----------/
 |     ^
 |     |
 \-0,1-/
```

Comment: Thank you for this comment, very helpful!